# Reverse the default transition of navigation controller in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to change the default transition of navigation controller i.e.
FROM
left to right
TO
right to left
when pushing a view controller and when I press back button then again change the default transition of navigation controller i.e.
FROM
right to left
TO
left to right

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(currentViewController, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

use this code sample:

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.8
transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
transition.type = kCATransitionFromRight // kCATransitionFromLeft
self.navigationController?.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(currentViewController, animated: yes)
```